# how to show brands images list in bigcommerce

Tags: bigcommerce

Dears i am using big commerce to show brands images on index now it is showing only the brands names but i want to list the brands images instead of brands names how i will show that

%%brandFullname%% show names of the brands like it there is any other global variable which show brands images instead of brands names

my code is

default page:

```
%%Panel.HTMLHead%%  <!-- Including the html head -->
 %%Panel.Header%%    <!-- Includeing the html Header -->
 %%Banner.TopBanner%%
 %%Panel.SideShopByBrandFull%% 
 %%Panel.SideCategoryList%%
 %%Panel.HomeNewProducts%%
 %%Panel.Footer%%
```

SideShopBybrandFull Code:

```
%%SNIPPET_SideShopByBrandFullList%%
```

SideshopByBrandFullList:

```
%%GLOBAL_BrandName%%
```

Any Help Appreciated

Regards

Answer (score 0):

The only place Bigcommerce can pull brand images is on the brands page itself. If you'd like the brands shown on other pages of the site you will need to find a different way to do it, such as creating your own panel with the HTML inside of it, requesting content through AJAX, or other methods.